# Get Outlook Reminders While App is Closed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications

Is it possible to have Outlook remind you of upcoming calendar appointments (and only appointments) while the application itself is not running? If so, how would that be set up?

Answer (score 2):

If the application isn't running then it can't send any reminders.

For this to work there would need to be two parts to Outlook. The first would be a Windows Service that could monitor the database and do things like send reminders etc. The second would be the User Interface that allowed you to read and send e-mails and set up reminders.

As far as I know Outlook doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a downloadable program that can display Outlook Reminders for you.

[Outlook Reminders 1.0](http://wareseeker.com/Information-Management/outlook-reminders-1.0.zip/3b44acf7c9)

If you are running Vista, you also us the built in [calendar system](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/calendar.aspx) to create reminders for you while the calendar is not open and running. In calendar options, chose "show reminders when calendar is not running".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I know this is an old question, but... there is a Windows Gallery object that will do this.  Works on Windows Vista & 7 with Outlook 2007 at least. You can find it here:

http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=de5f0006-ea77-4dca-abf3-949e6457d323&bt=1&pl=1

Answer (score 0):

I know thats a quite old post, but I just got a very nice solution to that issue.

Now in Windows 10 there is a nice Calendar program, which you can synchronize your Outlook account, though you can get Notifications from events without the e-mail temptations from your mailbox! In the end, you can actually get a bit of better performance on the PC as well.

Regards.

Comment: This is a perfect solution, and I have used it in the past. However, Microsoft are removing this Calendar program at the end of 2024. It's already gone from my work computer. 