# OneNote Drawing bug

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I use OneNote to take class notes, and sometimes, I will use the draw feature.

When I close the program and come back to the notebook later, the drawings will shift and be scrambled, making my notes impossible to read and a huge hassle to fix.

Has Microsoft released a 32-Bit edition update (other than `KB2288640`) to fix this?

Comment: Regarding your second question: `"Is it possible to make Outlook remainders/notifications active while Outlook is closed/offline"`, see this similar question: [*Outlook Reminders While App is Closed*](http://superuser.com/questions/69178/outlook-reminders-while-app-is-closed)

Comment: Please post questions separately. This makes it easier for others to contribute answers when they can only answer one of them.

Comment: Please download & install the [latest update for Microsoft OneNote 2010 (KB2589345) 32-Bit Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29774) and see if it helps.